# EXC_BAD_ACCCESS if creating object in dynamic framework

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, avcapturesession, dylib

I am a novice in using dyLibs in iOS, yet I tried to integrate one in one of my projects. A few weeks ago I thought that the same code that works in the mainproject would also work in a dyLib. Alas, I was wrong :-(

Let me show how did I create the object of `AVCaptureConnection`

```
let captureConnection = AVCaptureConnection()
```

this will be passed in the below function

```
func metadataOutput(_ output: AVCaptureMetadataOutput, didOutput metadataObjects: [AVMetadataObject], from connection: AVCaptureConnection)
```

When I call this method by passing the `captureConnection` and other required parameters in the dyLib, the app crashes with the following error:

> Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x28)

The app crashes even if I don't call the `metadataOutput` and just create the `captureConnection` object with the same error. Therefore, the issue is supposedly that we cannot create the `AVCaptureConnection()` inside the dyLib.

Any pointers on why this error occurs when written in a dyLib but not in the project itself might unblock us. It might be due to some preprocessing-flags that I need to introduce during compilation, but am not sure.

Even if someone can guide us on how to debug this issue would be of help and will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Adding links for miniaturized xcode project that reproduces the issue:

1. Without DyLib: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1i6GDIBaVekshshcmQWZKU6OXpNtg580e/view?usp=sharing

2. With DyLib: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BGv3Y32XdeQHG0U7fALT8o9iY_eI5dJW/view?usp=sharing

Comment: On my system, `let captureConnection = AVCaptureConnection()` doesn't compile at all.  It says there is no `init()` method in the class.  Apple's documentation agrees, listing 2 forms of `init`, each requiring parameters.

Comment: I am able to compile on Xcode version 10.3. On the other hand, Xcode version 11.4.1 doesn't compile it's saying the same there is no `init()` method in the class.